# tools: graphics and logo design

Tags: graphics

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Looking for a good free image editor](https://superuser.com/questions/25451/looking-for-a-good-free-image-editor)

My teenager wants to learn web graphics and logo design. What kind of tool are out there to help her get started. I would rather buy a cheaper tool to help her get started.

I would also like to get recommendations for animation and video editing.

This is for a teenager.. so we are looking for ease of use..

I need this for MAC OS.

Answer (score 9):

Gimp is free - www.gimp.org

Comment: Indeed - GNU Image Manipulator Program is quite sufficient for most image editing tasks, its scary name notwithstanding.

Comment: hopefully I will not get any viruses. Could this also be used for logo design?

Comment: +1, GIMP is an excellent program but isn't easy to use by any means. http://gimpology.com/ is an excellent site for some various tutorials

Answer (score 6):

Also check out [Inkscape](http://www.inkscape.org/).  It's a free vector/image program, good for logo work and design.

Answer (score 1):

I find Pixelmator a great application for image editing.  Has a lot of great features for a rather low price.  http://www.pixelmator.com/

Answer (score 1):

Another freebie Paint.net:

http://www.getpaint.net/index2.html

Rather good and easier to get going with than GIMP - but probably not as powerful.

Comment: Paint .Net is for Windows only.  The question states that it's for Mac OS.